# Как восстановить сайт на Wordpress после смены URL?

Tags: wordpress

Босс попросил "немножко поковыряться в сайте", сам я в этом "не в зуб ногой", но просили очень..  поковырялся, вроде пару текстовок сменил, Босс в восторге, попросил сменить URL сайта. Что-то, где-то найдя, я с довольным видом меняю URL и сайт перестаёт работать.
Сайт на WordPress, изменения делал с админской учётки. Сменил "cafe-hutorok.ru" на "cafe-edem.ru", собственно теперь выкидывает на левый сайт "cafe-edem.ru". Можно ли как-то "откатить" подобные изменения? 
http://cafe-hutorok.ru/

Comment: Можно всё лишь бы не ругали))) Но, вам нужен специалист. Не известно, где, что и в принципе зачем вы меняли домен сайта.

Comment: Будет вам уроком, что не надо браться за «не в зуб ногой»

Comment: Когда в следующий раз босс попросит "поковыряться" в его печёнке - соглашайся! А если попросит сделать пересадку сердца (а лучше - мозга) тоже не отказывай.

Answer (score 6):

Правильные решение - СРОЧНО обратиться к специалистам.
Или к хостеру за бекапом (если он есть и смотря какой свежести)

А если всё ещё хочется самому "поковыряться" - несколько способов описано в [ЧАВО/Восстановление адреса WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_WordPress) (если не поломаешь больше ;) )

*И больше НИКОГДА не лезь в то, в чем не в зуб ногой.*

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен доступ к файлам (например через SSH или FTP).

1. Сделайте резервную копию базы и файлов;
2. Почитайте [https://codex.wordpress.org/Редактирование_wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_wp-config.php)
3. В файл wp_config.php добавьте константы WP_SITEURL и WP_HOST с правильными значениями